# Adding an item to the vector without creating a temporary object

Tags: c++, vector, stl, compiler-optimization, c++03

Will compiler optimize this code, and not create a temporary string object?

```
std::vector<std::string> vector;
vector.push_back(std::string());
std::string& str = vector.back();
```

Comment: the right way would be using http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move

Comment: `vector.emplace_back();` certainly won't create a temporary object.

Comment: [`std::vector::emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back)?

Comment: Do ypu mean to `push_back()` without taking a copy? That's what `std::vector::emplace_back()` is for.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not using C++11, is there anything similar in earlier versions?

Comment: and I'm still annoyed, because every time I ask a question, people suggest me to do something else, without answering the question, it was about whether compiler will optimize or not (vs 2013, gcc4.9)

Comment: If you only want to add an empty string then you could just resize the vector.

Comment: @user1289 _"and I'm still annoyed ..."_ No, the compiler doesn't optimize that. And no there's nothing similar like `emplace_back()` in pre c++11 standard. Feel better with the answer now?

Comment: yes, this answer at least is related to the question I asked

Comment: @rex thank you, that would work in my case

Comment: @rex it's not that straightforward to compile a 20 year old project with C++11, there are reasons people don't use C++11, even though it has lots of advantages

Comment: @rex and user1289, `resize()` is still going to generate a temporary.  Unfortunately there is no way to get around that pre C++11.

Comment: Probably worth tagging the question with an old C++ version.

Comment: @NathanOliver Perhaps the earlier standard allows (but of course does not guarantee) copy elision?

Comment: @rex Yes it is allowed but IIRC this is not one of the situations where it applies.  `resize` is defined as `void resize( size_type count, T value = T() );` so it needs to make `value` which you can consider a temporary.

Comment: @NathanOliver Good point. Interesting to see the declaration was changed for C++11.

Comment: @NathanOliver I see, then std::vector<std::string*> will be the solution

Comment: Follow up question: How long do you think it takes to create an empty string?

Comment: @BoPersson Yes, good point. shouldn't take long, I didn't realize at first that it doesn't allocate at all in that case.

Comment: *"then 'std::vector<std::string*>' will be the solution"* I predict creating and discarding an occasional temporary string would be much cheaper than incurring an extra heap allocation for every single element (setting aside for a moment the added complexity of managing all that memory).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will [create a temporary std::string object](https://www.codingninjas.com/codestudio/library/vector-push_back-vs-emplace_back); it is standard behavior.

Use C++11 container methods `emplace_back()` or `emplace()` to store a std::string without while only calling the `std::string constructor` twice:

```
std::vector<std::string> vector;
vector.emplace_back("Hello!");
std::string& str = vector.back();
std::cout << str << "\n";
```

outputs:

```
Hello!
```

`emplace_back()` resizes the vector if needed.